# The type or namespace name does not exist - folders in C#

Tags: c#

I'm sure there is a simple solution to this problem, but it has defeated me so far. Basically all I'm trying to do is include some classes in a separate folder in my c# project.
Strangely this has been working just fine until today.

In the solution explorer I created a new folder called animations. 
I added the line to the main class:

using AnimationEditor.animations; (AnimationEditor is the solution name/namespace)

which throws the error:

Error   1   The type or namespace name 'animations' does not exist in the namespace 'AnimationEditor' (are you missing an assembly reference?)

As I said, I didn't have this error before today so I am a little confused.

Comment: Are you sure you have a class that is defined in a AnimationEditor.animations namespace?

Comment: The class Animations is declared with the namespace "AnimationEditor" ?

Comment: Creating a folder doesn't have anything to do with namespace names.  Yes, you are confused.

Comment: sorry for the confusing language, "animations" is just the folder which will contain some classes, I just wanted to have access to those classes from outside the folder.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you don't have the the line `namespace AnimationEditor.animations` in the the class you are trying to reference you need to manually add it.

Those `namespace` statements do not get automatically added when you move a file, they only get automatically put in when you create a new file under the folder.

So your class should look like

```
namespace AnimationEditor.animations
{
    class MyClass
    {
        //snip
    }
}
```

---

As a side note, [the .NET naming conventions](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms229026%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) state you should use a capital letter for those sub namespaces, capitalize the folder name and it will automatically capitalize the namespace for new files (you will need to manually change existing ones, just like moving)

Comment: Ah yes, once I created a new class in the folder, I was then able to add it with the "using" statement. I guess previously I had not tried to add the using line right after creating the empty folder. Still new to this c# stuff :P

Comment: Yes, you must have somewhere in your code the line `namespace Your.New.Namespace` at least once before you can start using `using Your.New.Namespace;`, just having the folder is not enough. Also, If I solved your problem please mark the answer as accepted using the check-mark below the voteing arrows.

Answer (score 0):

If you drag files to another folder (or add them) in visual studio, namespace does not change automatically (atleast in 2010). Check namespace of AnimationEditor class.